# Marketing and Fair Use

Tags: copyright, fair-use

The company I work for sells several products.  One has a title that lines up very well in the One Ring poem from Tolkien's LOTR.  I would essentially be replacing the phrase One Ring with the product title, and either leaving the rest the same, or perhaps a slight modification to the last line.  Is there any way this falls under fair use or would I need to get permission to do this?

The product in no way relates to anything Tolkien or fantasy or fiction for that matter. I don't believe it could be seen as an endorsement.

Answer (score 1):

You breach copyright when you substantially copy *or create a derivative work from* a literary work. A poem is a literary work; you need permission. From The Tolkien estate you won't get it.

Comment: That's what I figured.   Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Is it possible that, because this will take a work of fiction/fantasy and use it in a new scientific context, it would be considered transformative?  Although I would be replacing few words, the market space is science and most of the wording actually applies in a very unique way to this particular area of science?

Comment: That is a defense against trade mark infringement, copyright is universal.

Comment: I seem to find a lot of information that contradicts that statement. http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/four-factors/ being one.

Comment: I read what you linked - I think it supports what I said.